# Strategy for Generating a Normal Map Projection From a 3D Model

Tags: normals, normal-map

I am still relatively new to Blender, and I am currently using it to model 3D vehicles for a 2D game.

The 2D-rendering engine (Pixi.js) creates an illusion of depth using a normal map ([as demonstrated here](http://proclive.io/lights-in-pixi-js/)). What I would ideally like to do is take a specific perspective of my model and project a normal map on a plane that is perpendicular to the camera (where the color of each point in the normal map is calculated based on the normal's orientation relative to the camera).

What would be an appropriate strategy for doing this?

Comment: What you are describing is called "baking". You can find many tutorials on baking normal maps on Blender https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGv8UeZ5jxY

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed. I appreciate it.